# How to get single result as an array rather than a Model in Sequel ORM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel, roda

I am working on a simple application using Roda Ruby gem and Sequel. I want Sequel to return a single result as a array rather than a Model object type. When there is more than one item, it returns an array but when there's only one, it returns a Model item.

For example, in app.rb

```
get 'pizza' do
  @pizza = Pizza.first #=> returns object type Pizza, i want this to be a array as well
end

get 'pizzas' do
  @pizzas = Pizza.first(10) #=> returns an array of the first 10 results. 
end
```

If I could get a array instead of an Object type in the first case, I could use the same template for both. Otherwise it will be a bit of a hassle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I never worked with Sequel. Just out of curiosity: What happens if you use `Pizza.first(1)`?

Comment: Oh boy, it worked. thanks @spickermann ;)

Comment: Something is wrong with the question. `Pizzas.first(10)` does not return a `Hash`, it returns an `Array` of up to 10 `Pizza` objects. If that's what you want, then all is good, but the terms could do with changing in the question.

Comment: my bad, yeah sorry it does return an array. i will correct that. but still i wanted it to return a collection rather than an object. the solution in the correct answer still holds true :)

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. It is also possible to get hash forms of objects from Sequel, so it is important to make that clear. Thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `first` with an argument to trigger the array syntax. This works even when the argument is just `1`:

```
Pizza.first(1)
```